# WP Вывод произвольного элемента в меню после списка

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть вот такая функция для `function.php` файла, которая позволяет добавлять кнопку в меню, если есть потомки

```
//// Добавление  произвольного элемента в меню
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_button_for_mobile', 10, 4);
function add_button_for_mobile($item_output, $item, $depth, $args)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='" . $item->ID . "'");
    if ($has_children) {
        $item_output = '<button class="btn_nav__mobil" type="button" aria-label="Düğme alt menüsü"></button>' . $item_output; // Add custom elements
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как переписать эту функцию, что бы вместо кнопки у меня выводился `input` потом список потом `label` ... *Делаю AMP версию, там JS запрещён, хочу прокинуть слайд эффект через событие :checked и CSS

Пробую так, написать

```
//// Добавление  произвольного элемента в меню
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_button_for_mobile', 10, 4);
function add_button_for_mobile($item_output, $item, $depth, $args)
{

    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='" . $item->ID . "'");
    if ($has_children) {
        $item_output = '<input class="btn_nav__mobil__checkbox" id="mob-'. $item->ID .'" type="checkbox">' . $item_output . '<label class="btn_nav__mobil" for="mob-'. $item->ID .'"></label>'; // Add custom elements
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

Но это выдает не ту раскладку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<nav class="menu_second">
            <?php wp_nav_menu([
                    'theme_location' => 'navigation_menu',
                    'container' => false,
                    'fallback_cb' => '',
                    'echo' => 1,
                    'container_class' => '',
                    'menu_class' => 'menu_second__list bl_nav__list',
                    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                    'walker' => new Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                ]
            ); ?>
        </nav>
```

Comment: сделайте свой walker класс и переопределите в нем метод end_lvl  и start_lvl

Comment: можешь подсказать как это расписать ? я не очень силен в php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю вот так может выглядеть класс в вашем случае, не забудьте объявить свой `walker` при вызове `wp_nav_menu`

```
class Custom_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    private $item_id = [];

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0 ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        $class_names = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';

        $atts           = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        if ( '_blank' === $item->target && empty( $item->xfn ) ) {
            $atts['rel'] = 'noopener';
        } else {
            $atts['rel'] = $item->xfn;
        }
        $atts['href']         = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $value ) && '' !== $value && false !== $value ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output = '';

        if ( in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
            $this->item_id[$depth] = $item->ID;

            $item_output .= '<input class="btn_nav__mobil__checkbox" id="mob-'. $item->ID .'" type="checkbox">'; // Add custom elements
        }

        $item_output .= $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent  = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";

        if ( isset( $this->item_id[ $depth ] ) ) {
            $output .= '<label class="btn_nav__mobil" depth="' . $depth . '" for="mob-' . $this->item_id[ $depth ] . '"</label>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чёт подключил, в меню (код добавил в вопрос), но инициализация дополнительних элементов не произошла, не понимаю как это дело дебажить

Comment: а куда добавили сам класс?

Comment: `function.php` файл

Comment: как вариант вы можете сделать var_dump(1234)  допустим в методе  start_el, если на фронте не появятся 1234 то вы неправильно подключили  класс либо не к тому меню

Comment: появился вывод, и даже 2 раза

Comment: похоже что у вас переопределяются классы пункта меню, вы можете в методе start_el найти условие if ( in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) { и заменить его на это global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='" . $item->ID . "'");
    if ($has_children) {

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это решило вопрос.